# using same function for two purposes

Tags: php, function, session, return-value

I have a function called `isLoggedIn()` - This returns a `FALSE` or `TRUE` based on whether the user is logged in or not. It does this by checking if the user data is set in session.

I have another function called `getUserSession()` which fetches and returns the user data in session. My question is: Is it ok to merge them both?

I mean isLoggedIn() is already accessing the session values, so if I return that in the function, then I use it like so:

```
//when I need session data
$user = isLoggedIn();
echo "Hello ".$user['name'];

//when I need to check if user is not logged in
if(!isLoggedIn())
{
 echo "Please login to proceed!";
}
```

Is there a problem with this approach? My colleague says I should not merge them, but I do not see what the concern is here...

Comment: What are you trying to gain by merging them? You can make a function that returns session data if logged in, and FALSE if logged out, if you really wanted to.

Comment: Well, I thought it was kind of redundant to do have two functions, and we were doing some refactoring to remove dead/duplicate code., so I thought this might be a candidate for that.

Comment: Of course you /can/. It sounds like you know that already and you're asking for opinions. Mine, for the record, is: if it's feasable without having to change too much dependent code, do it. If not, no sweat. It wouldn't be a noticable difference anyway.

Comment: `function isLoggedIn(){ return (isset($_SESSION)) ? $_SESSION : false; }`

Comment: keep them separate, you'll have a cleaner code. compare the caller side for the two approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your going to merge them do something like this

```
if($user = isLoggedIn())
{
 echo "Hello ".$user['name'];
} else {
 echo "Please login to proceed!";
}
```

Comment: This will not work. Because it will always give true irrespective of whether user is logged in or not, since you are using an assignment operator in  `if()`

Comment: @open_sourse can you please explain further, if your function `isLoggedIn` - `return false;` when you are not logged in this will work ...

Comment: when you place `$user = isLoggedIn()` inside the `if` condition, it will return true if the action succeeded. The action here is assigning value of `isLoggedIn()` into `$user`. So no matter what the return value of `isLoggedIn()` is, the `if()` condition will return `true` because `$user` was assigned that value - hence this code will give incorrect results.

Comment: @open_sourse thats incorrect. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/968d607743089577501d03b34f501083154378ed

Comment: you are right, my apologies. I always thought assignment operators inside `if()` always returns true

Answer (score 0):

You can merge them, but you need some sort of value to correspond to someone not logged in. For example, if you had a function called `getUserSession()` that simply returned `$_SESSION['User']` you might want to implement it something like:

```
function getUserSession() {
    return isset($_SESSION['User']) ? $_SESSION['User'] : NULL;
}
```

Now `NULL` will represent an invalid session (User not logged in). All you have to do is check if your session is NULL and you know the User is not logged in.

```
$user = getUserSession();
if ($user != NULL) {
    //Stuff here with a valid session
} else {
    //Do stuff if the user is not logged in
}
```

Comment: No reason to throw NULLs into the mix. Just return false

Comment: I mean, why is false any better than NULL. Just needs to be some sort of distinct value, preferably of a different type than the expected, valid value.

Comment: Because then you can do `if($user)` and `if(!$user)`.

Comment: Fair enough... I do like shorthand =D

Comment: @Insertusernamehere And I do like your long name :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can of course merge such functionality. Simple when user doesn't exist you return false and you return userdata if user exists and you can use it as you showed in your question

In fact if possible you **should do it** because it's easier to change and maintain your code in case of any changes.

There is one thing you should consider - if you do any operations in this functions that may affect your performance - for example querying database. Probably you should use some kind of cache in this case but if you don't each time you check if user is logged you would query database to get userdata/make any checks in database and it could be some loss for your performance.

Answer (score 0):

The concern is if you happen to return anything that could be evaluated as a `false`. That includes `0`, an empty string, `"false"`, an empty array, some of which could be a valid session value. For example, if you had no session values, then it would return an empty array (or an empty string), which would evaluate `if(!isLoggedIn())` to be true.