# Why does this code work correctly? - using equal sign inside an if condition

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean, variable-assignment

Why does this code work correctly?

```
function isLoggedIn(){
 return false; //or true
}

if($user = isLoggedIn())
{
 echo "Hello ".$user['name']; //if isLoggedIn returns true, this prints
} else {
 echo "Please login to proceed!";//if isLoggedIn returns false, this prints
}
```

I always thought `assignment operator` inside an `if()` condition will always evaluate to `true` since it is only evaluating whether the value of `right hand side` can be assigned to `left hand side`...

Comment: *"Why does this code work correctly?"* - Now there's a switch.

Comment: lol, I guess there is :p

Comment: I noticed you've taken it from the answer given earlier http://stackoverflow.com/a/24539850/ why the question here? Curious.

Comment: I did not understand that answer, and the comments section would become too long and only have the OP's answer, so I thought I'd post here.

Comment: I understand. Well, it seems like you've gotten your money's worth below. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition considers $user after assignment.
Therefore it will be true or false depending on the value returned by isLoggedIn()

There is one note. Code like this will not work as expected:

```
if($var = someFunction() && $var !== 'bad') {}
if($var = someFunction() && $var === 'good') {}
```

Because $var will contain not a value returned by someFunction(), but a boolean value of the whole expression, like this:

```
$var = (someFunction() && $var !== 'bad');
if($var) {}
```

To get the result you need you should use brackets:

```
if(($var = someFunction()) && $var !== 'bad') {}
if(($var = someFunction()) && $var === 'good') {}
```

You can find details [on the php.net website](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

Answer (score 4):

It's evaluating the value of `$user` after assigning the return of `isLoggedIn()` to `$user`.  It's the same as:

```
$user = isLoggedIn();
if($user) {}
```

It's especially handy in loops:

```
while($var = someFunction()) {
   //do stuff with $var
}
```

And more expressions:

```
if($var = someFunction() && $var !== 'bad') {}

if($var = someFunction() && $var === 'good') {}
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, an assignment operation actually has a return value, and it's the value that was assigned. Your `if()` condition works for the exact same reason that

```
$x = $y = $z = 42;
```

works. This statement will assign the value `42` to all three variables, and is functionally the equivalent of

```
$z = 42;
$y = $z;
$x = $y;
```

In your case, your `isLoggedIn()` function call will execute and return a value. That value assigned to `$user`. Then that value is "returned" to the if() statement itself and is used for the logic test.

If your function had returned boolean false, or a "falsey" value, then the "else" clause would have executed. e.g.

```
function returns_false() {
   return false;
}

if ($foo = returns_false()) {
   echo 'if was true';
} else {
   echo 'if was false';   // this line will get executed
}
```

Even though the assignment operation succeeded, it's the value that got assigned that matters, not the success/failure of the operation. so the "it was false" code path gets executed, because the function call returned a `false`, which propagated up the decision tree.

Answer (score 0):

It works because the IF is TRUE.  Oddly enough it will always be TRUE.  Because you are assigning the value when you only use one = sign.  If you want to check the contents, you have to use ==.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has already suggested, there are two parts to the statement:

1. It assigns the value of isLoggedIn() to $user.
2. It then returns the same value to whichever construct asked for it. In this case, it's
   returned to the if () statement.

It is worth noting that although the if () statement expects to receive a boolean value true or false. If the if () receives a value that isn't a boolean, it is still acceptable in PHP (as well as JavaScript). If any operator or statement receives a value of the wrong type, PHP will convert it to boolean=true in most cases.